# Google TV, Access Google Drive using Android API not possible

Tags: google-drive-api, google-tv, google-play-services

We are building an app where we needs to access files stored at google drive.
We are able to run our app other than google tv.

Reason found so far:-
Google Play Services are not available for google TV.
us there any alternative to access Google Drive File at Google TV.

Thanks 
Dev Team

Comment: I don't get the question. Can you rearrange the words and add a questionmark somewhere? Check http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking for help on asking. It increases your chance on a good answer dramatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do the OAUTH2 in a WebView and use the raw api's.  https://developers.google.com/drive/

and

https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-java

You'll probably need to use different support libraries for TV.

Comment: I already did the same. Authentication using web-view.any ways many thanks